# Writing a bash script to get a specific line from Stackdriver monitoring

Tags: bash, logging, scripting, environment-variables, gcloud

I am trying to run a bash script to get a specific line from the Stackdriver logs, if found then it should exit, or else sleep for 5 minutes, and then try again by getting current date from **environment variable** and then apply it, if not found on second attempt then it should fail.

Specified an environment variable to get current timestamp so that I could pass onto the logs.

```
CHIEF=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z)
```

The command I am using to stream the logs is

gcloud logging read `"logName=projects/testing1/logs/syslog timestamp>=\"2019-09-25T10:55:56.992Z\" AND timestamp<=\"$CHIEF\""`

Lets say i want to extract the log "Access Denied", How can i construct this bash script please?

Thanks

Comment: You are not `getting current date from environment variable`.  You are getting it from the system clock and assigning it to a variable.  The variable you are assigning it to is not being put in the environment.  (Merely naming a variable with all-caps does not make it an environment variable.)

Comment: The general pattern you might want to use is: `cmd | if grep -q pattern; then ...; else ...; fi`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Stackdriver Logging documentation, it's decent:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview

I recommend trying your queries using Google Cloud Logging viewer:
https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer

Switch the query to advanced mode. That will help yield the filter you want.

Your filter needs to restrict the logs not only to the log and timestamp but to the specific value `Access Denied`. It's unclear to me where this would appear in your syslog but the Log Viewer should help you narrow this down.

You may then apply a format, either gcloud's built-in `--format=...` or, the more general purpose `--format=json` and then pipe the result into e.g. jq.

This is one way to solve your problem. I make no warranty that it's the best way ;-)

```sh
FILTER="logName=\"projects/testing1/logs/syslog\" "\
"jsonPayload.message:\"Access Denied\" "\
"timestamp>=\"2019-09-25T10:55:56.992Z\" "

for LOOP in first second;
do
  CHIEF=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z)
  MESSAGE=$(\
    gcloud logging read "${FILTER} AND timestamp<=\"$CHIEF\""" \
    --format="value(jsonPayload.message)")
  if [ "${MESSAGE}" == "Access Denied" ]; then
    echo ${MESSAGE}
    break
  fi
  sleep 5m;
done
```

**NB*

- `FOR loop in first second` is cumbersome but, it works
- Pay attention when concatenating filter strings, this gets messy.
- You should (!?) be able to use `CHIEF=$(date --rfc-3339=s)`
- I'm using a `jsonPayload.message` and `:` (contains|has) for the value
- I'm using `--format=value(...)` but there are other ways to [format](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/filtering-and-formatting-fun-with)
- This assumes that `jsonPayload.message` is only `Access Denied`. This is unlikely, you should do some regex or substring check

HTH!